# iOS - Convert Audio Format (opus to mp3)

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3, wav, opus

Recently I started to develop application that work with .opus file (Audio Format).

I am working with external SDK that can processor a mp3/wav file, unfortunately my local file is a .opus file and I need to convert it to mp3/wav format in order to process the file.

I read and research a lot around the network to find a solution,
I found the FFmpegWrapper library that can convert two type of Audio Format but when I try to convert .opus to .mp3/ , I get this error: **opus codec not supported in WAVE format**
I do not know what can be done, I'll be happy to help.

Any information about how to convert .Opus format to any other format will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using this pod: https://github.com/chrisballinger/Opus-iOS
You can use it to convert your Opus-encoded file to wav, then feed it into your SDK.

Comment: It would be better if you give example how to do instead of just giving pod name.